# X.509 Certificate From Private Key

Tags: saml, x509

I was sent a private key in plain text form to be used to Encrypt/Decrypt  SAML2P request and response messages. However the routine that I'm using require an X.509 certificate. How do I store the private key in an X.509 certificate so that it may encrypt and decrypt the message.

Comment: If you really merely got a private key, you do not have the certificate. But there are some transport formats which contain both the certificate and the private key. To help you one has to know the exact format used for your private key.

Comment: The private key, which is the part of the keypair, is not used to encrypt the data. 

So there are several cases possible: (a) you have a symmetric key, which is secret and which you use for both encryption and decryption, or (b) the key is the private key but you are assumed to also obtain the certificate somewhere, or (c) you've been given the RSA private key, but you are using the library which is not suitable to your needs, while you need a library that can work with RSA keys. 

You need to redefine your needs and update the question accordingly.

Comment: @mkl - As I said in the post the key was sent to me has plain text in an email message. I wish to use X509Certificate2 object to contain both the private and public keys.

Comment: @Mayevski - I'm working with an IdP (STS) server that utilizes SAML 2 the private key was sent to me to decrypt the response from the authnRequest. The routines that I'm using use the X509Certificate2 object and expect the private key to be in a x509 certificate. I'm unclear how I import a private key into a certificate.

Comment: @Mike*As I said in the post the key was sent to me has plain text in an email message.* - there are multiple plain text variants possible here. Thus, please be more specific.